# Bing maps library "Cannot set property 'isLoaded' of undefined" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, bing-maps

I am using upgraded v8 Bing Maps library. I have placed grouped markers on the map. Everything shows up properly but still I get this following error in the console log.

**Cannot set property 'isLoaded' of undefined**

This error is pointing towards this particular line of code.

```
 n.moduleLoaded = function(t) {
            var i, r, u;
            if (t) {
                for (i = n._supportedModules[t],
                i.isLoaded = !0, //this particular line triggers error
                r = 0,
                u = i.pendingCallbacks.length; r < u; r++)
                    i.pendingCallbacks[r]();
                i.pendingCallbacks = []
            }
        }
```

Below is how supportedModule is defined:

```
n._supportedModules = {
            "Microsoft.Maps.DrawingTools": {
                dragonflyObjectName: "DrawingToolsModule",
                isLoaded: !1,
                pendingCallbacks: []
            },
            "Microsoft.Maps.WellKnownText": {
                dragonflyObjectName: "WellKnownText",
                isLoaded: !1,
                pendingCallbacks: []
            },
            "Microsoft.Maps.GeoJson": {
                dragonflyObjectName: "GeoJson",
                isLoaded: !1,
                pendingCallbacks: []
            },
            "Microsoft.Maps.SpatialDataService": {
                dragonflyObjectName: "GeoDataAPIManager",
                isLoaded: !1,
                pendingCallbacks: []
            },
            "Microsoft.Maps.AutoSuggest": {
                dragonflyObjectName: "AutosuggestManager",
                isLoaded: !1,
                pendingCallbacks: []
            },
            "Microsoft.Maps.HeatMap": {
                dragonflyObjectName: "HeatMapLayer",
                isLoaded: !1,
                pendingCallbacks: []
            },
            "Microsoft.Maps.Clustering": {
                dragonflyObjectName: "ClusterLayer",
                isLoaded: !1,
                pendingCallbacks: []
            },
            "Microsoft.Maps.SpatialMath": {
                dragonflyObjectName: "SpatialMath",
                isLoaded: !1,
                pendingCallbacks: []
            },
            "Microsoft.Maps.Search": {
                dragonflyObjectName: "SearchManager",
                isLoaded: !1,
                pendingCallbacks: []
            },
            "Microsoft.Maps.Traffic": {
                dragonflyObjectName: "TrafficManager",
                isLoaded: !1,
                pendingCallbacks: []
            },
            "Microsoft.Maps.AdvancedShapes": {
                dragonflyObjectName: "",
                isLoaded: !0,
                pendingCallbacks: []
            },
            "Microsoft.Maps.Directions": {
                dragonflyObjectName: "DirectionsManager",
                isLoaded: !1,
                pendingCallbacks: []
            },
            "Microsoft.Maps.DataBinning": {
                dragonflyObjectName: "DataBinningLayer",
                isLoaded: !1,
                pendingCallbacks: []
            },
            "Microsoft.Maps.Contour": {
                dragonflyObjectName: "ContourLayer",
                isLoaded: !1,
                pendingCallbacks: []
            },
            "Microsoft.Maps.VenueMaps": {
                dragonflyObjectName: "VenueMap",
                isLoaded: !1,
                pendingCallbacks: []
            }
        },
```

Comment: I don't know bing-map... But from what I see, I think the only way `i` can end up `undefined` is because of a `t` passed to this function not beeing in the `n._supportedModules` definiton. Hope it helps.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette t has a value hence it enters inside the if block & reaches the line of error.

Comment: Yes... What I say is that it certainly has a value that is not in the `n._supportedModules` object. Try to console.log(t) for fun...

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using to load the map and any modules you are loading. There is no issue with the internal code you provided.

Comment: @rbrundritt I found the root cause for this error but still confused over why is it occurring. I have a file scripts.js & another file PointBasedModule.js.
Pointbasedmodule.js contains module script & last line of this file calls moduleLoaded function with it's moduleKey.
Scripts.js has registerModule for the above module with the path of the script in the above file.

I am loading scripts.js first so that module gets registered before being called. But it's triggering the moduleloaded of that last line in the registerModule itself.

Comment: Very odd. I can't reproduce this. What module key are you using? Can you provide the code you are using for registering, loading the module.